# How to choose from functions with the same name in C++

Tags: c++

I have this simple code in C++

```
#include <something.h>
#include <something2.h>

int main()
{
    my_function();
    return 0;
}
```

function with name my_function is defined in `something.h` and also in `something2.h` How to choose whichone I want to use without editting included files?

Comment: Find whoever wrote the included files and beat them until they stop polluting the global namespace?

Comment: Surely it won't compile if it's ambiguous?

Comment: Put it in a compilation unit that only includes one of those headers. But really, the first comment is *the right way*.

Comment: Because _"violence is never the answer. Namespaces are. Violence is just the means"_ ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use

```
namespace something_one
{
   #include <something.h>
}
namespace something_two
{
   #include <something2.h>
}
```

This works well if all the code is in the headers.

Otherwise you have to resort to `#define`s, stub functions implemented in carefully crafted compilation units, or a robust conversation with the global namespace polluter.

Comment: ‘*This works well if all the code is in the headers.*’ could use some emphasis.

Comment: he need to modify the main.cpp as well. I think linking the specific "something.o" or "soemthing2.o" file depending upon requirement would be better, if no code changes to be made in the source files.

Comment: OP does say "defined in something.h". Of course, that could be an abuse of the term, but I took it literally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that actual definition resides in `something.cpp` (or .c) and `something2.cpp` (or .c),

Link only one of `something.o` or `something2.o` at the time of creating `main` application executable, depending upon from which file you want function to get executed.

With linking the correct file, you do not need to change any source code.

- you might have to declare them as `extern "C"` at the point declaration and definition if you are compiling it as c++ files with `g++` or `gcc -std=c++0x` or `gcc -std=c++11`.